# TheBennyBox Engine - Performance Friendly Instanced Static Meshes Like In UE4

Tags: java, opengl, instance, mesh

I'm using the java game engine made by thebennybox to create my own engine. Previously I worked with UE4 where you could have Static Mesh Actors, in his engine this would probably be a GameObject with a MeshRenderer component attached to it:

```
GameObject staticMeshActor_Grass = new GameObject();

AddObject(staticMeshActor_Grass.addComponent(new MeshRenderer(
    new Mesh("plane.obj"), new Material(
    new Texture("T_Grass_BC.png"), 1, 8, 
    new Texture("T_Grass_N.png")))));
```

Now I'm trying to create a large field of these grass tiles but since these are all their individual GameObjects (or Actors in UE4 terms) after 16x16 tiles it starts to cripple the frame rate!

I believe I can solve this problem if I make instances of multiple static meshes inside one GameObject in order to make it performance friendly. In UE4 this feature is called 'Instanced Static Mesh Component' which allows for that and I would like to have something similar.

Here's the GameObject class made by thebennybox:

```
public class GameObject
{
    private ArrayList<GameObject> m_children;
    private ArrayList<GameComponent> m_components;
    private Transform m_transform;
    private CoreEngine m_engine;

    public GameObject()
    {
        m_children = new ArrayList<GameObject>();
        m_components = new ArrayList<GameComponent>();
        m_transform = new Transform();
        m_engine = null;
    }

    public GameObject AddChild(GameObject child)
    {
        m_children.add(child);
        child.SetEngine(m_engine);
        child.GetTransform().SetParent(m_transform);

        return this;
    }

    public GameObject AddComponent(GameComponent component)
    {
        m_components.add(component);
        component.SetParent(this);

        return this;
    }

    public void InputAll(float delta)
    {
        Input(delta);

        for(GameObject child : m_children)
            child.InputAll(delta);
    }

    public void UpdateAll(float delta)
    {
        Update(delta);

        for(GameObject child : m_children)
            child.UpdateAll(delta);
    }

    public void RenderAll(Shader shader, RenderingEngine renderingEngine)
    {
        Render(shader, renderingEngine);

        for(GameObject child : m_children)
            child.RenderAll(shader, renderingEngine);
    }

    public void Input(float delta)
    {
        m_transform.Update();

        for(GameComponent component : m_components)
            component.Input(delta);
    }

    public void Update(float delta)
    {
        for(GameComponent component : m_components)
            component.Update(delta);
    }

    public void Render(Shader shader, RenderingEngine renderingEngine)
    {
        for(GameComponent component : m_components)
            component.Render(shader, renderingEngine);
    }

    public ArrayList<GameObject> GetAllAttached()
    {
        ArrayList<GameObject> result = new ArrayList<GameObject>();

        for(GameObject child : m_children)
            result.addAll(child.GetAllAttached());

        result.add(this);
        return result;
    }

    public Transform GetTransform()
    {
        return m_transform;
    }

    public void SetEngine(CoreEngine engine)
    {
        if(this.m_engine != engine)
        {
            this.m_engine = engine;

            for(GameComponent component : m_components)
                component.AddToEngine(engine);

            for(GameObject child : m_children)
                child.SetEngine(engine);
        }
    }
}
```

The AddObject() method shown in the first part comes from an abstract class and eventually calls the method AddChild(GameObject child) inside the GameObject class. As you can see we have an ArrayList of GameObjects and GameComponents. Now I would have to implement some method in order to support the creation of multiple mesh instances inside one GameObject.

I've already tried to add multiple MeshRenderer components to one GameObject but this didn't work out. Maybe someone has a suggestion how I might go about this?

if you're really interested and want to help me you can download the engine here: https://github.com/BennyQBD/3DGameEngine

Just use 'Open Projects From File System..' in eclipse, choose the directory of this folder and once you've done that you should be able to run the program.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score -1):

this might be what you are looking for:

http://www.java-gaming.org/topics/issues-with-batching-meshes/37809/view.html

They mention that ThinMatrix has created a tutorial about instancing meshes, hope this helps you!